# Controller output

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

Today i am trying to understand coding principles with Code Igniter framework. Nevertheless, i faced with stupid problem.

Here is my controller grades:

```
<?php
class Grades extends CI_Controller
{
    public function view()
    {
        $data['todo_list'] = array('Clean House', 'Call Mom', 'Run Errands');

        $data['title'] = "My Real Title";
        $data['heading'] = "My Real Heading";

        $this->load->view('pages/home', $data);
    }
}       
?>
```

And here is mine home:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php echo $heading;?></h1>

<h3>My Todo List</h3>

<ul>
    <?php foreach ($todo_list as $item):?>

    <li><?php echo $item;?></li>

    <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

The output is:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: pages/home.php
>
> Line Number: 11
>
> ---
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: heading
>
> Filename: pages/home.php
>
> Line Number: 6

May I have missed something? I would like to find out how to solve this problem.

Routes.php

```
$route['grades'] = 'grades';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: I think you want just `$route['default_controller'] = 'Grades'; $route['(:any)'] = 'Grades/$1';`

Answer (score 0):

There is not error in your controller or view file, but there is a problem in routes

$route['grades'] = 'grades';
**should be
$route['grades'] = 'grades/view';**

$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
**should be
$route['default_controller'] = 'grades/view';**

you have to notice that in routing works like
$route['{is_the_string_will_appear_in_URL}']='{is_a_controller_name}/{is_a_method_name}/${will_be_first_parameter}'
Please let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the elements properly. Try like this

```
<?php foreach ($data['todo_list'] as $item):?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Err1:
Change `:` to `;` on line 11!

Err2:
You must define the variable `$heading` before use it. It doesn't have any value now.

Comment: A mistake lies into route.php, but i don't know hot to fix it :/

$route['grades'] = 'grades';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['404_override'] = '';

Comment: You were defined `$data['heading']` not `$heading` !

Comment: $this->load->view('pages/home', $data); // as you can see i transfer data

Comment: @Rahnamafard that's wrong as you can see on codeigiter's guide page http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html and the `:` is right, it is the other way of using the foreach.